# ошибка 209 sql. Не могу доработать sql запрос. Только начал заниматься и сложно понять

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

Нужно посчитать количество забитых голов каждым игроком за весь чемпионат мира.
Смог просуммировать количество голов каждым игроком и расположить их в порядке убывания. Но нужно сделать INNER JOIN по ID_Players к другой таблице что бы Получить его имя и его забитые голы.

### Вот так я вывожу айди игрока и суму его голов

```
SELECT ID_Players, SUM(NumberOfGoals) AS Goaledor
FROM NumberOfGoals
GROUP BY ID_Players
ORDER BY Goaledor DESC;
```

### А вот так вот пытаюсь связать айдишники. Помогите пожалуйста решить этот вопрос.

```
SELECT ID_Players, SUM(NumberOfGoals) AS Goaledor
FROM NumberOfGoals
Inner join Players ON NumberOfGoals.ID_Players = Players.ID_Players
GROUP BY NumberOfGoals
ORDER BY Goaledor DESC;
```

[image: Таблица игроков[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPX7p.png)

Comment: SQL Server - это не MySQL... список тегов исправлен.

Comment: Ладно... а вопрос-то какой?

Comment: Подскажите как правильно сделать INNER JOIN между этими двумя таблицами. Я пытаюсь что то делать, но постоянно новые ошибки

Comment: К INNER JOIN как раз претензий нет. Есть претензии к неоднозначности поля. Ну и пытаться суммировать ТАБЛИЦУ - это вообще за гранью... PS. Сообщения об ошибках следует цитировать - с точностью до пробелов и переводов строк.